# Decode remote JSON file gives no response

Tags: php, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm trying to get a file that has been json_encode'd with PHP.
The file is on a different domain, no matter what I try I'm not getting ANY result.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://cdn2.realhardstyle.nl/data/radio/nowplaying.rhr',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            alert('test');
        }
    });
```

For example, I only need the value of [ID], But I am getting nothing at all, no erros, no console log mentions about anything that could be the issue but the alert is also not showing itself.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `$.getJSON('Your url here', function(data)) { //do something }`

Comment: check the network tab of  console

Comment: Note the response is JSON, not JSONP, and that means your request may be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 2):

That url gives you a JSON resource not jsonp

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://cdn2.realhardstyle.nl/data/radio/nowplaying.rhr',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $('body').append(data[0].id);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```